# "All the organizations involved have sent ...." sentence structure problem

Tags: sentence-construction, reduced-relative-clauses, participle-phrases, participial-adjectives

**[SOURCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/appeal)** (Longman's dictionary)

Please do me a favor to teach me grammar structure as following sentence

> All the organizations **involved** have sent urgent appeals to the government, asking for extra funding.

Questions

1. **involved**, is it adj?
2. **involved**, why after (All the organizations)?
3. why use "," split two sentences?

Comment: Let's start with the subject. What does **organization** mean here? One structured group? Many? Or the activity of organizing?

Comment: Sorry @Davo I have used wrong word , not "included" ,it should be "involved"

Comment: Ah. I believe this is an ellipsis of an adjectival phrase: All the organizations *(which are/were)* involved...

Comment: When you quote a source, please always include a link to that source in your question. This makes it easier to write a useful answer. Also, when citing an online source, you should copy and paste the text rather than trying to re-type it; this often introduces errors, as you found.

Comment: “Involved” is an adjective here. It’s one of a number of adjectives that can occur both attributively and postpositively, though with different senses. For the sense intended here, it is a postpositive i.e. it occurs after the noun that it is modifying. The clause _asking for extra funding_ is modifying _appeals_ and is inherently restrictive, so no comma is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You present the following example sentence from the *Longmans dictionary* definition of the verb *appeal.*

> All the organizations involved have sent urgent appeals to the government, asking for extra funding.

The answers to your questions are:

1. *Involved* is the past participle of *to involve*, used here as an adjective
2. Present and past participles such as *involved* occur fairly commonly after the noun they modify. Adjectives of the kind are called *postpositive* or *postnominal* adjectives.
3. The comma in your sentence does not "split" two sentences, since *"asking for extra funding"* is not a sentence.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for mentioning the error(s). I just wrote the answer based on the original source that I'd found on the internet.

Comment: hi, it seems you were prejudiced about one of my questions and accused me for some things that are inaccurate, Shias and Sunnis have the same opinion over this matter (my question); however, there are other ideological or historical debates, but it has never been the cause of war; Wahhabism and ISIS which are supported by Saudi Arabia, and are the result of Britain interferes and support of Arabs against Ottomans is another story; you can delete this message and for more discussion, we can talk in a chat.

Comment: @Ahmad The subject is off topic here, and your comment has nothing to do with this question or answer.

Comment: @P.E.Dant you say this to me? Did you forget that you started it? As I said, you can delete these comments. I just replied your comments which was out of a prejudice.

Answer (score 1):

Participles can take several roles, they can be used after nouns to describe them.

Here, the past participle **involved** means **which are involved**. In fact, you can consider the sentence as a reduced relative clause:

> All the organizations [which are] involved have sent urgent appeals to the government, asking for extra funding.

Regarding your last question, as I said above, participles can act as adverbs. When a participle clause is used as adverb, it's preceded by a comma.

In details, that participle adds a new information to the previous sentence: that the appeal was about requesting extra fund.

Comment: "Involved" is an adjective here. The gerund-participle clause _asking for extra funding_ is not adverbial; it is modifying the noun _appeals_ and is inherently restrictive, so no comma is required.

Comment: @BillJ Hmm, so you say that the appeals are asking for extra funding? I thought Organizations are asking for extra funding. By the way, what is the name of such participles? Adjunct?

Comment: The appeal gives the details, cf. "An appeal asking for extra funding has been sent ...", where the clause is clearly modifying the noun "appeal". Similarly, in a relative construction: "The organizations involved have sent the government urgent appeals which are asking for extra funding", where the relative clause is modifying the NP "appeals". "Asking for extra funding" is a gerund-participle clause.

Comment: @BillJ That comma made think that's a adverbial participle.

Comment: No, it's not adverbial. It's a modifier in noun phrase structure, i.e. _**appeals** to the government, *asking for extra funding_.